# Is NativeBase pure React Native?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to fully understand the meaning of this statement:

> NativeBase is a mobile application development framework which enables
>   developers to use React Native to build native mobile applications
>   running on the major mobile platforms - Apple iOS and Google Android.

What does "development framework" mean exactly? If I were to get one of the NativeBase Starter Kits, am I getting pure React Native code or is it like Expo and isn't pure React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nativebase is actually a ui kit for react-native. As you know react is a frameworks which is used to build reusable components.Nativebase provides a lot of ready to use components which makes your development process faster & you don't have to put great efforts in developing complex UI components.

We can say nativebase is not a development framework but its a library & react is a development framework.